# How to debug HTTP AUTH params in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rubyists,

something's wrong with my HTTP AUTH params that are coming into my Rails 3 app. The password  has some whitespace at the end. I was debugging my client app and it looks like it is sending it correctly.

I am doing this in my app:

```
params[:auth_username], params[:auth_password] = user_name_and_password(request)
```

Then I am sending this into Warden.

I would like to see the raw data to see if the whitespace is there. How to do that?

**Edit**: I have debugged the wire between httpd and thin process and I am pretty sure the data are coming correctly. It must be something wrong in my Rails 3.0.10. I was able to decode the base64 string that is coming in the headers and it did not contain any whitespace.

This really looks like BASE64 decoder issue. Maybe a padding problem. My string is:

```
Qmxvb21iZXJnOnRjbG1lU1JT
```

which decodes to

```
Bloomberg:tclmeSRS
```

correctly using non-Ruby base64 decoders. Even in Ruby:

```
>> Base64.decode64 "Qmxvb21iZXJnOnRjbG1lU1JT"
=> "Bloomberg:tclmeSRS"
```

I don't get it. Searching for a bugreport in Rails or something like that.

**Edit**: So it turns out our Apache **httpd proxy** adds something to the header:

```
Authorization: Basic Qmxvb21iZXJnOnRjbG1lU1JT, Basic
```

This leads to the incorrect characters at the end of the password, because:

```
>> Base64.decode64('Basic Qmxvb21iZXJnOnRjbG1lU1JT, Basic'.split(' ', 2).last || '')
=> "Bloomberg:tclmeSRS\005\253\""
```

The question is now - **is this correct**? Is it a bug in httpd or rails?

Comment: Seems that the issue is with your httpd configuration. The `, Basic` part sounds weird to me.

Comment: Was a bug in our apache httpd configuration: RequestHeader append Authorization "Basic" early

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails `user_name_and_password` method makes a call to `decode_credentials` that performs the following, then splits using ":" :

```
::Base64.decode64(request.authorization.split(' ', 2).last || '')
```

Applied to your data :

```
::Base64.decode64("Qmxvb21iZXJnOnRjbG1lU1JT".split(' ', 2).last || '').split(/:/, 2)
=> ["Bloomberg", "tclmeSRS"]
```

Everything seems to be ok, the problem sits elsewhere IMO. To dump the authorization data from your controller :

```
render :text => "Authorization: #{request.authorization}"
```